# How to automatically log into another site if CSRF-Token is required (PHP, SSO, LDAP)

Tags: php, ldap, content-management-system, single-sign-on

I'm trying to create an intranet site where, if possible, all parts of it should be SSO in a way that a user who is logged into his Active Directory account in Windows would immediately be signed on with that same account in all pages of my site through LDAP.
Now the main component of this site is built with a CMS and from there the user should be able to click the links on this site to get to the other tools we're using, like for example the ticket system.
The CMS and the ticket-system software both are able to connect through LDAP themselves but I want a SSO solution for this.

So I searched and found this for the apache server: `mod_authnz_sspi`
This apparently lets you use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']` in PHP to get the windows user signed on right now. 
Now I'm stuck since I'm not really sure how to use this to automatically log the user into the sites.
What do I have to do with this to get the SSO solution that I want?

I thought about creating a simple HTML form with the same fields like the one from the ticket-system form I'm trying to log into. I would then try to send the POST-data to the form of the ticket-system and log the user in automatically. For the username I would send `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` and for the password `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']`. However, the ticket system is protected with a CSRF-Token which I would have to include into the sent POST-data but can't know in advance since it is generated in the moment of accessing the page.

So it would be really helpful if someone could tell me how to get a SSO working with the `mod_authnz_sspi` tool (or another).
If there isn't any other way than through using a HTML-form that sends the POST data like I tried, then it would be helpful if someone knew a workaround to the CSRF-Token problem!

Comment: The whole point of CSRF tokens is to stop people doing things such as what you're trying to do. And what you're describing is not true SSO anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an AUTH application that administrate your users (details, permissions, etc.). When an user access other application if it are not logged in redirect it to the AUTH application. AUTH application check user credentials, generate an access_token and redirect user back to the application that try to access. More info you find here https://www.mutuallyhuman.com/blog/choosing-an-sso-strategy-saml-vs-oauth2/